# How to refresh a jQuery UI Slider after setting min or max values?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, max, min

I have a ui.slider and change its min and max values on runtime. But these changes only get reflected in the view, when I set the values afterwards too (which causes it to fire events that are not needed). In my opinion, it should refresh the view after setting min and max too. Is there a simple workaround, seems like a refresh method is missing for the slider.

```
$("#something").slider({
    range: true,
    values: [25, 75],
    min: 0,
    max: 100
});
$("#something").slider("option", "min", 25); // left handle should be at the left end, but it doesn't move
$("#something").slider("option", "values", [25, 75]); // the left handle is now at the left end, but doing this triggers events
```

**Edit** This issue has been fixed in jQuery UI 1.9

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't know whether this is a bug in the jQuery UI slider, but anyway, what you can do is change the current value (technically, setting the current value to the current value...) to force the view to be refreshed. Following [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#method-value), this would mean doing something like this :

```
$(function() { 
    var $slide = $("#something").slider({
        range: true,
        values: [25, 75],
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    });
    $slide.slider("option", "min", 25); // left handle should be at the left end, but it doesn't move
    $slide.slider("value", $slide.slider("value")); //force the view refresh, re-setting the current value
});
```

Comment: This was my first attempt too, but this trigger the change event etc. and is therefore not as aesthetic as I'd like it to be ;). Thanks anyway, seems like this is the way to go if I don't want to patch the slider plugin itself.

Answer (score 2):

Cracked the handle reposition issue... just call this function..

```
function resetSlider(){
    $("#slider-fill").attr('value',maxPrice);
    $("input[type='range']").slider( "refresh" );//refresh slider to max value
    $(".ui-slider-handle").css("left","100%");
    console.log("Slider Reset Done.");
}
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: no such method 'refresh' for slider widget instance

Comment: Make sure, I am talking about jQuery Mobile!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the minimum slider value like:

`$slide.slider("option", "min", 25);` does not work for me.

Instead I used: `$slide.slider("values", "0", 25);` and everything is working fine.

For setting the maximum slider value, use `$slide.slider("values", "1", 75);`

For more information on setting values, see the api docs - http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-values

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
valPercent = (current_slide_value - min_value) / (max_value - min_value) * 100;     
parentElem.find('.ui-slider-range').css('width', valPercent+'%');    
parentElem.find('.ui-slider-handle').css('left', valPercent+'%');
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a version issue but nothing I tried with options "min / max" worked. This is OK and tested with JQuery UI 1.10. This way you can use either the slider or the numbers to change the other one:

```
$("#mySlider").slider({range: true, min: 0, max: 100, values: [ 0, 100 ], step: 10,
   slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $("#mySliderMin").val( ui.values[ 0 ]);
      $("#mySliderMax").val( ui.values[ 1 ]);
   }
});
$("#mySliderMin").val($("#mySlider").slider( "values", 0 ));
$("#mySliderMax").val($("#mySlider").slider( "values", 1 ));
$("#mySliderMin, #mySliderMax").change(function () {
   $("#mySlider").slider("values", 0, $("#mySliderMin").val());
   $("#mySlider").slider("values", 1, $("#mySliderMax").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the html div in jquery function as

```
var d='<div class="row grid_slider"><div><p>Grid With time in 24 hour format</p><input type="text" class="range_time24" value="" name="range" /></div></div>';document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML=d;
```

Then set new values to slider

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$("#Slider2").slider("value", 10, 1000); //10 = min and 1000 = max
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-create the slider by first removing it with:

```js
$('.slider').slider('destroy')
```

and then set up your slider again with the correct options.

Answer (score -3):

You need to keep a reference to your slider object,

```
var slider = $("#something").slider({
               range: true,
               values: [25, 75],
               min: 0,
               max: 100
             });
slider.slider("option", "min", 25);
```

This is all listed in the [Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#method-option)

Comment: No, a reference is not needed. Setting the minimum works, BUT the visual state of the slider doesn't change.