# Change jQuery UI Slider Value Based on Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to setup ticket price calculator which shows you the price per ticket based on a selected location.

The values for the ticket price calculator are based on the `value` attribute that's set in the `select` form.

All of my code works except for the `$('region').on('change')` action. I simply can't get the data in the calculator to update to the new values.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2hmcf5wf/1/

```js
$(function() {

  // setting up region variables
  switch ($('#region').val()) {
    case '10':
      var cost = 10,
        time = 300;
      break;
    case '20':
      var cost = 20,
        time = 600;
      break;
  }

  // slider
  $('#slider').slider({
    max: time,
    min: cost,
    step: cost,
    value: cost,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      update(cost, time, ui.value);
    }
  });

  // set initial values
  $('#ticket').html('1 ticket');
  $('#price').html('$' + $('#slider').slider('value'));

  // region change
  $('#region').on('change', function() {
    update();
  });

});

function update(cost, time, value) {
  $('#ticket').html((value / cost) + ' ticket');
  $('#price').html('$' + value);
}
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

#region {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<select id="region">
        <option value="10" >Los Angeles, CA</option>
        <option value="20">New York, NY</option>
    </select>
<div id="slider"></div>
<span id="ticket"></span>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="price"></div>
```

Comment: you wrote:  `$( '#region' ).on( 'change', function() { update(); });`  but your function expects 3 arguments: `function update( cost, time, value )`

Comment: [jsfiddle working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/vLg1nvss/), it also keeps the position of the slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code, the immediate issue is that your `update` invocation within your change listener isn't passing the proper arguments. Change it from `update();` to `update(cost, time, this.value)` and it should work.

Additionally (assuming that the intended behavior is to use the `cost` and `time` values that are calculated at the top in your case/switch statement. On the region value change you'll want to recalculate the `cost` and `time` variables. In addition, you'll want this to affect the callback in your slider. I'd do something like this to make sure that everything works, basically, just make `cost` and `time` global variables and update them prior to the `update` function invocations.

```
var cost, time;

$(function() {
    // setting up region variables
    changeRegion($( '#region' ).val());

    // slider
    $( '#slider' ).slider({
        max: time,
        min: cost,
        step: cost,
        value: cost,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            update(ui.value);
        }
    });

    // set initial values
    $( '#ticket' ).html( '1 ticket' );
    $( '#price' ).html( '$' + $( '#slider' ).slider( 'value' ) );

    // region change
    $( '#region' ).on( 'change', function() {
        changeRegion(this.value);
        update(this.value);
    });

});

function changeRegion(value) {
  switch ( value ) {
      case '10':
          cost = 10, time = 300;
          break;
      case '20':
          cost = 20, time = 600;
          break;
  }
}

function update( value ) {
    $( '#ticket' ).html( ( value / cost ) + ' ticket' );
    $( '#price' ).html( '$' + value );
}
```

**Edit:**

Also, in addition, you'll need to refresh your slider to update the reflected changes in the time and cost variables. See [How to refresh a jQuery UI Slider after setting min or max values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333152/how-to-refresh-a-jquery-ui-slider-after-setting-min-or-max-values) as an example, you'll need to invoke something like this in order for the slider to reflect those changes:

```
sliderObject.slider("option", "min", cost);
sliderObject.slider("option", "step", cost);
sliderObject.slider("option", "max", time);
sliderObject.slider("value", cost);
```

Comment: Add `var newValue = $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value" )/cost;` before the switch, and `newValue *= cost` after the switch to keep the slider position

Answer (score 1):

You don't have data in parameters, because you simply don't pass them. Just change `update()` to `update(cost, time, $('#slider').slider('value'));`

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! I updated the code to reflect those changes but it still doesn't appear to work. I do agree with that this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Move switch into change event and declare that variables on top of function.