# Storing values of UI Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, uislider

After spending hours on several tutorial books and online help I am not able to figure out my problem.Here i am trying to store values of UI slider using localstorage object and it is working fine ( i am getting stored value on every page load) but  UI slider pointer not moving according to stored value
 it shows position as zero(0) on every page load.

Any suggestion would be a great help

Thanks

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step:25,
    value:show(),
        change: function() {
                iremember();
          },
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
          $.post('volume.php', {volume: ui.value}, function(data) {
          });
          $('#volume').val(ui.value+' %');
        }
  });
});

function iremember()
{
var dataTosave=document.getElementById("volume").value
localStorage.setItem("intdata",dataTosave)
}

function show()
{
var dataToshow=localStorage.getItem("intdata")
document.getElementById("volume").value=dataToshow
}
</script>


html-----

<div class="def_class" id="slider-range"></div>
<input type="text" id="volume"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333152/how-to-refresh-a-jquery-ui-slider-after-setting-min-or-max-values/6334834

Answer (score 1):

Your function `show()` should return a value:

```
function show() {
   var dataToshow=localStorage.getItem("intdata");
   document.getElementById("volume").value=dataToshow;
   return parseInt(dataToshow);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying . I did the same changes in the code. But UI Slider pointer is locked now :(

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my answer. Since you store a string e.g. '30%' it has to be converted to a number. I've missed that at the first time.

Comment: it worked like a charm. you are owsome Kosh Very.. Thank you so much :)